# A que se debe este error en ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Este es el codigo

```js
render() {
    this.customize();

    return (<ReactF1
      id="ResponsiveHeader"
      data-f1="header" 
    >
      <h1>Hola</h1>
    </ReactF1>);
  }
```

Y este el error:

> Unexpected token, expected ;
>   line 6, column 10
>   Work/src/components/header/index.js

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Supongo que sera por algo de syntax pero ni idea.

Comment: En tu codigo sobra un `}`

Comment: Tienes razon, pero de todas formas sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Si. haha no queria decir con ello que el error se solucionara, solo como anotacion. Si lo solucionara habria hecho una respuesta, no un comentario ^^

Comment: Jaja ok, gracias. Aun estoy aprendiendo el uso de este foro :p

Comment: La he editado para quitar ese `}` extra. y ademas he quitado el error de la imagen y puesto como texto en la pregunta. asi si el enlace de la imagen se rompe la pregunta todavia tiene sentido

Comment: A mí me parece que hay un error de sintaxis *antes* del render.

Comment: No creo porque antes del render solo tengo esto

import React from 'react';
import ReactF1 from 'react-f1';

Comment: Estas usando Clases o funciones? Creo que debes editar la pregunta y poner el código del componente completo.

Comment: Ese es todo el codigo del componente @devconcept, es eso y los import, nada mas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando una sintáxis invalida. Creo que tu intencion fue usar una clase ya que mencionas que estás usando `import` es muy probable que tengas soporte para clases también.

Tu método render sería un método de la clase y la clase el componente como tal.

```js
import React, { Component} from 'react';

class MiComponente extends Component {
  render() {
     this.customize();
     return ( 
       <ReactF1 id="ResponsiveHeader" data-f1= "header" >
         <h1>Hola</h1>
       </ReactF1>
     );
  }
}

export default MiComponente;
```

Lee https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.component

No se para que es la función `this.customize()` pero me parece que lo que estás creando es un componente de presentación por lo que no debes incluir otro código en la función render a menos que sea necesario por alguna librería.

Lee https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Si no estás usando ES6 deberías usar esta sintáxis donde el método render es una propiedad de un objeto

```js
var MiComponente = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <ReactF1 id="ResponsiveHeader" data-f1="header">
         <h1>Hola</h1>
      </ReactF1>
    )
  }
});
```

Lee https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html

Si te das cuenta la declaración `render` debe llevar el identificador `function`, ya que es una función o ser miembro de una clase de ES6 para no llevarlo.